# Svelte and Jquery - Dropdown.svelte:7 Uncaught TypeError: jquery(...).dropdown is not a function

Tags: jquery, svelte, svelte-3

I am trying to use Semantic UI (Which uses jQuery) in Svelte. I am trying to initialize the dropdown function, but I am getting the following error : Uncaught TypeError: jquery(...).dropdown is not a function. I am not sure why this is happening.

Dropdown.svelte

```
  <svelte:head>
       <script src="jquery.js"></script>
       <script src="dropdown.js"></script>
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dropdown.css">
   </svelte:head>

   <script>
      import { onMount } from 'svelte';
      import jQ from 'jquery';

      onMount(() => {
        jQ( document ).ready(function() {
        jQ('.ui.selection.dropdown').dropdown();
      });   
     });

  </script>

  <div class="ui selection dropdown">
     <input type="hidden" name="gender">
     <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
     <div class="default text">Gender</div>
         <div class="menu">
            <div class="item" data-value="1">Male</div>
            <div class="item" data-value="0">Female</div>
         </div>
     </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that Semantic's components expect jQuery to already be available as `window.jQuery` when you load their JS.

Here's, for example, an extract from `dropdown.js` (see [the line](https://github.com/fomantic/Fomantic-UI/blob/2f3312f0f075e3a570dc96725be17e965b3b0964/dist/components/dropdown.js#L4202) on Github):

```js
;(function ($, window, document, undefined) {
...
})( jQuery, window, document );
```

So, you've got to ensure `jQuery` is loaded and attached to `window` before loading Semantic's JS.

The reason your code fails to achieve this is because the content of `<svelte:head>` is only appended to the DOM when the component is rendered, not before. Immediately after render, `onMount` is called, but the `<script>` tag that has just been added has not finished loading at this point.

You could synchronize by listening the `load` event of this script, but that's convoluted and that won't bring you far. The problem is that the content of these `<svelte:head>` is appended *for each instance* of the component. This doesn't work well for components that can appear multiple time on the page.

So, what can we do? One solution is to load jQuery before your bundle in your `index.html`:

```html
    <script src="/vendor/jquery.js"></script>

    <script type="module" defer src='/build/bundle.js'></script>
```

With this, you're guaranteed that jQuery will be available before your bundle's code is executed. In your `Dropdown.svelte`, you'd have code like this:

```html
<script>
  import { onMount } from 'svelte'
  import '../semantic/dist/components/transition.js'
  import '../semantic/dist/components/dropdown.js'

  // you should also probably make your bundler process & manage your
  // CSS dependencies, because in <svelte:head>, CSS links could be
  // duplicated at runtime -- you'll need a Rollup / Webpack CSS plugin
  import '../semantic/dist/components/reset.css'
  import '../semantic/dist/components/transition.css'
  import '../semantic/dist/components/dropdown.css'

  onMount(() => {
    jQuery('.ui.selection.dropdown').dropdown()
  })
</script>

...
```

Another option is to synchronize your imports. With normal ES import, you can't have any guarantee on the order they will be processed. But you can do it with dynamic imports. This would give you code like this:

```html
<script>
  import { onMount } from 'svelte'
  import jQuery from 'jquery'

  // import the required CSS, somehow

  onMount(async () => {
    if (!window.jQuery) window.jQuery = jQuery
    await import('../semantic/dist/components/transition.js')
    await import('../semantic/dist/components/dropdown.js')
    jQuery('.ui.selection.dropdown').dropdown()
  })
</script>

...
```

You will need to make your bundler config just right to enable dynamic imports in your project though.

Comment: thanks for the answer. After following your suggestions, I am not getting the original error. But I am getting a different error now: Transition: Element is no longer attached to DOM. Unable to animate. I tried resolving this error, but I am unable to do so.

Comment: It seems to be working for me with your code. I've pushed an example on a branch in [this repo](https://github.com/rixo/playground-svelte/tree/example-fomantic) (notice: it's not on master). See if it can help. Also, like I said, I don't recommend adding the CSS in `<svelte:head>`, so don't copy that from my repo!